# How to trigger firestore cloud functions on update of field value?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to send email to user on update of status field of user to value (true) using firestore and cloud functions.

My case :
I have a users(collections) which has more documents of userId(documents) and each document contains field and value.
One of the field is status: true | false (boolean).

I want to send email to that user if status of that user change to true using cloud functions and sendgrid api.

```
users
   - dOpjjsjssdsk2121j131
        - id : dOpjjsjssdsk2121j131
        - status : false
   - pspjjsjssdsdsk2121j131
        - id : pspjjsjssdsdsk2121j131
        - status : false
   - yspjjsjssdsdsk2121j131
        - id : yspjjsjssdsdsk2121j131
        - status : false


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {  
   const after = change.after.val();

    if(after.status === 'VERIFIED'){
      console.log('profile verified')
      const db = admin.firestore();

      return db.collection('users').doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
         const user = doc.data();
         const msg = {
           to: 'email',
           from: 'email',
           templateId: 'template id',
           dynamic_template_data: {
            subject: 'Profile verified',
            name: 'name',
        },
       };

       return sgMail.send(msg)
   })
   .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
   .catch(err => console.log(err) )

    } 

  });
```

Comment: Could you provide information about what exactly is not working with your code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting your error because in Firestore where is no `val()`.

Try to change your `change.after.val()` to `change.after.data()`, so your code looks like this:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {  
   const after = change.after.data();

    if(after.status === 'VERIFIED'){
      console.log('profile verified')
      const db = admin.firestore();


      return db.collection('users').doc(context.params.userId)  // get userId
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
         const user = doc.data();
         const msg = {
           to: 'email',
           from: 'email',
           templateId: 'template id',
           dynamic_template_data: {
            subject: 'Profile verified',
            name: 'name',
        },
       };
       return sgMail.send(msg)
   })
   .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
   .catch(err => console.log(err) )
    } 
  });
```

Comment: how to get the userId before return.db.collection('users').doc(userId) . ?

Comment: I think you have to use `change.after.id ` to get the userId or `after.id` because you are also storing the id in your db.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can compare the target field by before and after data, if your target field is not the same. It means the field value has changed.

    const beforedata=change.before.data()
const afterdata=change.after.data()

if(afterdata.status == beforedata.status){
// Status not changed
}else{
//status changed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**All correct for the above answer except "context.params." is missing from *(staffId)***

Currently:

> ```
> return db.collection('users').doc(userId)  // get userId
> ```

Should Be:

```
>     return db.collection('users').doc(context.params.userId)  // get userId
```

This will also answer the above comment:

```
how to get the userId before return.db.collection('users').doc(userId) . ? – Fortray Sep 6 '19 at 9:13
```