# Is there a way to send a notification to the app (using FCM or token) when an image file is added to Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Users are uploading images from the web to Fire Storage. I want to send a notification to the client app when the image is uploaded. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to send a notification to the app (using FCM or token) when an image file is added to Firebase Storage?

Yes, you can [trigger a function on Cloud Storage changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#trigger-function-on-storage-changes):

> Use functions.storage to create a function that handles Cloud Storage events.

Alternatively, you can store the [URL of the image you have uploaded to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660) into the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), and again trigger a function on document update, as explained in the following answer:

- [How to trigger firestore cloud functions on update of field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818168/how-to-trigger-firestore-cloud-functions-on-update-of-field-value)